# Shocks and guesses

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

The Liar, the Random and Truth teller were captured and brainwashed to forget whether they always lie or tell truth or randomly answer.Everyone is handcuffed to a chair and gagged with gray, white and black scarf. Each one was given a phone with apps to guess who among them is the right Liar,the Random and Truth teller or else will be electrocuted. The apps below with 9 buttons will give them a painful electric shock every time they select a button that is a wrong guess.  4 shocks is fatal.Buttons must be pressed one at a time. The 3 correct buttons should be pressed.
[image]

1) The Liar will receive the shock if his guess is true.
2) The Truth teller will receive the shock if his guess is false.
3) The Random teller will receive the shock if 2 consecutive guesses are both true or both false.

What buttons should be pressed to survive, figure out everyone's identity with the fewest trials and shocks?

Comment: Does each see what guess any other has made, and what the outcome of that is? Do they have to guess simultaneously? What do you mean by at least 3 buttons have to be pressed - does each have to press three buttons, or do you mean all of their presses together? Does the game end when they are all certain what type they are, or when they all have made a correct guess at some point, or when the last guess of each person is correct?

Comment: I see now that each person has to make a guess at the identity of all three of them. Is the shock only given once one button is pressed on each row? Can you press two or more buttons in the same row? And if so, how is the truth value of such a guess determined?

Comment: at jaap all button can be pressed assuring all 3 right buttons are pressed but not a good strategy

Comment: each don't see what guess any other has made, and what the outcome of that is.. and they have to guess on their time.. What do you mean by at least 3 buttons have to be pressed ? the right ones even already known.

Comment: @ jaap- the shock is given once one button is pressed if it should be. You can press two or more buttons in the same row one at a time.  And the truth value is determined by their original character before memory erasure.

Comment: I put in an edit that makes it more clear what you are trying to say

Comment: So a person can select any (sub)set of the 9 buttons, and when that selection is finished then the truth value is determined and a shock given if necessary. If the truthteller selects all 9 buttons, he won't get a shock because the three correct buttons are included in his selection. Similarly, if the liar selects all 9 buttons, he will get a shock for the same reason. Is that correct?

Comment: Pressing the button one at a time will result in shock or no shock. One person knowing the 1) 2) 3) rules and the color of his scarf can make his first guess by pressing a button.

Comment: If three consecutive guesses for Random is true, is it two shocks? Or does the counter reset after a shock?

Comment: Each person knows the colour of their scarf? Also do they have to guess their own identity only, or the identities of others? Also can they see each other's guesses? Also do they function as a team (willing to take shocks as an individual to minimise shocks for the team)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood the puzzle correctly, it's a nice and easy puzzle, and the only reason it has not been answered by now, is the lack of clarity in how it's worded. Here is my take on it:

> [image]

Below, is how I read the puzzle:

You and two other people are in single cells: yours is painted gray, another is white and the last is black. You know one of the three people is a Liar, one makes Random statements and one is a Truth teller. You have been brainwashed to forget whether you always lie or tell truth or randomly answer. You, personally, are given a phone with an app to guess who is the the Liar, the Random and the Truth teller or else you will be electrocuted. The app below with 9 buttons will give you a painful electric shock according to the rules below as you select buttons. 4 shocks are fatal. If you survived after having pressed the three correct buttons (in any order or sequence) you are let go.

[image]

1. If you are the Liar, you will receive a shock if your guess is true.
2. If you are the  the Truth teller, you will receive a shock if your guess is false.
3. If you are the Random, you will receive a shock if your last two 2 consecutive guesses are both true or both false.

What buttons should be pressed to survive, figure out everyone's identity with the fewest trials and shocks?

Comment: Would you kindly edit the op wordings to eliminate any further clarification?

Comment: @TSLF I'm not sure if I understood it correctly ;)

Comment: @TSLF based on that you validated my reading by accepting the answer, I edited my answer to add my reading of your puzzle. Feel free to use it if you feel it helps.

Comment: For clarification. Can I select the same button twice or some  color will lit up the button to indicate it was selected thus any accidental touch wont shock me again?

Comment: @TSLF nowhere it was indicated, that buttons would lit up on touch. So when they get lit/unlit is unclear and probably not important. Whether you will be shocked again or not on touching the same button again depends on if you are Random or not, and also on the preceding touch. You always can select the same button twice. You may be shocked if you do.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one possible solution, and possibly *pain* optimal.

> Everyone presses the *Truth* button. No one gets shocked because the Truth teller is telling the truth, the Liar is lying, and the Random guy does not get shocked till he makes 2 choices.
>
>
> Everyone then presses the *Truth* button again. This time, only the Random guy will get shocked, because both his choices are false. The other 2 don't get shocked because of the same argument above. This confirms who the Random guy is.
>
>
> Now the unshocked guys both press *Random*. The Truth teller will get shocked because he is telling a lie. The Liar won't be shocked because he is lying. And thus both will know who is which. 
>
>
> This solution thus requires 3 trials and 2 shocks at the most.

To be more concrete :

> Whatever scarf color I am, I press *Truth* twice. If I am shocked in the second try, I am Random and I do not press anything (or if I am supposed to always press a button when the others are pressing, I press *Random* and don't get a shock because the previously I pressed wrong, and this time I pressed correct). If not, then I press *Random*. If I am shocked, I am the Truth teller, because I told a lie, and I cannot be the Liar because I would not have been shocked then. If still not shocked, then I am the Liar.

Comment: if you are one of them and know just your scarf color and the 1) 2) 3) rules. What button should you press first?

Comment: rot13(Gehgu, Gehgu, Enaqbz. Vs fubpxrq va gur svefg 2 gevnyf, gura V nz Enaqbz. Vs abg, gura vs fubpxrq va gur guveq gevny, V nz Gehgu gryyre. Ryfr Yvne.)

Comment: jung vf gur pbybe bs lbhe fpnes?

Comment: rot13(Qbrf abg znggre)

Comment: Gura jub vf gur gehgu gryyre naq gur Yvne vs lbh ner gur enaqbz?

Comment: rot13(Vg vf abg cbffvoyr sbe zr gb xabj jub vf jung rkprcg zl bja vqragvgl orpnhfr gur bayl vasbezngvba V nz cevil gb vf gur vasbezngvba V tngure sebz gur ncc. Rirelbar bs hf pna svaq bhe bja vqragvgvrf naq gung;f gur orfg jr pna qb orpnhfr gurer vf ab rkpunatr bs vasbezngvba.)

Comment: there are 3 truth buttons which two did you press twice?

Comment: Wait, your question is unclear. Which *Truth* button? I have a phone with an app that has 3 buttons, right? And I can press 1 of them. I don't know what the others are pressing on their phone. Just my phone. Own phone. Right? What I am reading is equivalent to 3 of us having a phone each with an app with 3 buttons, T R and L and the 3 of us are some thousands of miles away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107729/discussion-between-tslf-and-yuzuriha-inori).

Answer (score 3):

> Everyone click the truth button. By doing this, the truth teller will always tell the truth and won't be shocked. The liar will always lie, and won't be shocked. Random teller will be shocked once but thats unavoidable.

Comment: they are handcuffed with one free hand to use the phone apps

Comment: wait I read it wrong @TSLF